# Script not printing with php

Tags: php, html

when i am using like this in html is script is working fine

```
{category: "Auto", measure: 6600},

    {category: "Best Car", measure: 22200},

    {category: "Car Auction", measure: 5400},

    {category: "Car Audio", measure: 60500},

    {category: "Car Battery", measure: 6600},
```

but when i am trying to print this with php like this

```
<?php foreach($rows as $row){ ?>    
        {category: "<?php echo $row['ad_group']; ?>", measure: <?php echo $row['volume']; ?>},
    <?php } ?>
```

it is not working.

Comment: How printed string looks like?

Comment: Yeah give what your output is coming.

Comment: like this {category: "Auto", measure: 6600},
  
  {category: "Best Car", measure: 22200},
  
  {category: "Car Auction", measure: 5400},
  
  {category: "Car Audio", measure: 60500},
  
  {category: "Car Battery", measure: 6600},
  
  {category: "Car Buying", measure: 18100},

Comment: Yes, what is not working?

Comment: This is json isn't it? can't you form the structure as an array then encode it?

Comment: i tried with json but it is not working

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: i copied source code into php and removed php code then it is working. i think there is some problem with printing

Comment: `JSON` would be the right way to do it as it solves also formatting problems and fixes some security issues that might arise (like XSS).

Comment: holy f&*% 2 upvotes!?!?!

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ad_group] => Auto
            [volume] => 6600
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ad_group] => Best Car
            [volume] => 22200
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ad_group] => Car Auction
            [volume] => 5400
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ad_group] => Car Audio
            [volume] => 60500
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [ad_group] => Car Battery
            [volume] => 6600
        )

)

Comment: i tried like this foreach($rows as $row){
  $data1 .= json_encode($row);
 }
 echo $data1;

Comment: when i tried with json it is printing like this {"ad_group":"\u0000A\u0000u\u0000t\u0000o\u0000","volume":"\u00006\u00006\u00000\u00000\u0000"}{"ad_group":"\u0000B\u0000e\u0000s\u0000t\u0000 \u0000C\u0000a\u0000r\u0000","volume":"\u00002\u00002\u00002\u00000\u00000"}{"ad_group":"\u0000C\u0000a\u0000r\u0000 \u0000A\u0000u\u0000c\u0000t\u0000i\u0000o\u0000n\u0000","volume":"\u00005\u00004\u00000\u00000\u0000"}{"ad_group":"\u0000C\u0000a\u0000r\u0000 \u0000A\u0000u\u0000d\u0000i\u0000o\u0000","volume":"\u00006\u00000\u00005\u00000\u00000"}

Comment: Its not working because the trailing `comma` is breaking the syntax.  Just encode it, the entire array, look at @srain answer.

Comment: @Flosculus it is printing like this when i use json [{"category":"\u0000A\u0000u\u0000t\u0000o\u0000","measure":"\u00006\u00006\u00000\u00000\u0000"},{"category":"\u0000B\u0000e\u0000s\u0000t\u0000 \u0000C\u0000a\u0000r\u0000","measure":"\u00002\u00002\u00002\u00000\u00000"}

Comment: Right, thats normal, it just means the json requires the data be encoded to a transportable format and `json_encode` has done this for you

Comment: does i have parse it in javascript

Comment: Its a data interchange format, naturally something will need to decode it, but any json decoder will work.

Answer (score 2):

You can put all the data into a `$list` and then use `json_encode()` to encode it.  This will also make sure your values are properly escaped.

```
<?php
$list = array();
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    $data = array();
    $data['category'] = $row['ad_group'];
    $data['measure'] = $row['volume'];
    $list[] = $data;
}
echo json_encode($list);
?>
```

See also: http://php.net/json_encode

Comment: it is printing like this [{"category":"\u0000A\u0000u\u0000t\u0000o\u0000","measure":"\u00006\u00006\u00000\u00000\u0000"},{"category":"\u0000B\u0000e\u0000s\u0000t\u0000 \u0000C\u0000a\u0000r\u0000","measure":"\u00002\u00002\u00002\u00000\u00000"}

Comment: It seems that content of `category` contains some Unicode charset.

Comment: @raghavendra Iterate and alert/log the values, you will probably find the data is intact (at least as much as when it was formulated).

Comment: @raghavendra, did I post something error. About your last comments.

Comment: @raghavendra, where do you want to show the result? the console or webpage?

Comment: when i try like it is fine var dataset = [
 <?php foreach($rows as $row){ ?> 
  {category: "<?php echo $row['ad_group']?>", measure: 0.30},
 <?php } ?>
   ]
   ;

Comment: problem is coming with $row['volume']

Comment: in db $row['ad_group'] is a varchar does this effects?

Comment: {category: "Auto", measure: 0.30},
  
  {category: "Best Car", measure: 0.30},
  
  {category: "Car Auction", measure: 0.30},
  
  {category: "Car Audio", measure: 0.30},
  
  {category: "Car Battery", measure: 0.30}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45449/discussion-between-srain-and-raghavendra)

Comment: when i mouse over it is showing title as irregular characters

Comment: which character set i can use in db

Comment: db structure CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `adwords` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `session` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ad_group` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `keyword` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `avg_monthly` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `volume` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `competition` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `suggested_bid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=801 ;

Comment: It has no relation with the charset. What is your output? let's move to the chat here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45449/discussion-between-srain-and-raghavendra